# I am having issues with getting the desired output on Spyder

Tags: python, printing, spyder

The code I run:

```
def areatriangle(base, height):
    area = .5 * base * height
    print("Area of the triangle of base",base,"and height",height,"is", area)
```

The output I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Python/spyder/Exercises.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Python/spyder')*
```

Comment: what kind of problem or error are u facing. can u share some picture.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) `runfile` is the command used by Spyder to run a file in the console. So every time you run files from the Editor, you'll see it displayed in the console and there's nothing wrong with that.

Besides that, you are not seeing any other result because you're not calling the `areatriangle` function, you are simply declaring it and that doesn't produce any result. So, you need to add the following to your code

```
def areatriangle(base, height):
    area = .5 * base * height
    print("Area of the triangle of base",base,"and height",height,"is", area)

areatriangle(1, 2)
```

and then you'll see the following

[image: Evaluation]

Comment: Okay Thank youuu

Comment: No problem, I hope you enjoy working with Spyder.